# Can't export my .ipynb file as a PDF from VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to export a .ipynb file from VSCode as PDF. But, I keep getting an error:
'Export failed. Please check the 'Jupyter' output panel for further details.'

I want to export the .ipynb file as a pdf, with all the markdowns and the code snippets.

Comment: I am able to export it as a html file though. I working around this by first exporting it as html file and then converting it to a PDF file.